# IOException ошибка (Теория)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть вот такой код. Из-за чего может произойти `IOException`?

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build();

FormBody.Builder builder = new FormBody.Builder()
    .add("code", par[1]);


if (data[0] != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        builder.add(key[i], data[i]);
    }
}

RequestBody formBody = builder.build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(par[0])
    .post(formBody)
    .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    String serverAnswer = response.body().string();
    return serverAnswer;

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "1";
}
```

Comment: Не могу вычеслить ошибку. Когда происходить запрос на мобильных данных return "1". При этом на некоторых телефонах все окей а на других реторн "1"

Comment: а дебагом пользоваться умеете?

Comment: @JVic Дебаг запускает приложения в эмуляторе там все окей и на моем телефоне все окей но проблема возникает на некоторых телефонах

Comment: точно так же подключаете чужой телефон к пк и дебажите. Без этого мобильная разработка не существует

Comment: @JVic а если я не могу взять чужой телефон?

Comment: А по стеку не видно, где возникает исключение?

Comment: вы в главном потоке в инет запрос шлете?

Comment: @TimurVI  нет с помощью AsyncTask в отдельном потоке

Comment: Не надо один вопрос задавать два раза. Первый вопрос зада нормально, а этот оформлен отвратительно.

Comment: Покажите стектрейс.

Comment: проблема в том что я не имею доступ к стектрейсу

Comment: >>проблема в том что я не имею доступ к стектрейсу << Это очень странно. Без вопроса (а стектрейс, по сути, указывает в чём именно проблема) - здесь вам могут дать сотни предположений что могло быть. ИМХО, вы всё равно эти предположения не рассмотрите, проще показать логи. Освойте логгер, заставьте делать FileAppender, и вы таки, получите годный стейктрейс для анализа. Сделайте это, и облегчите жизнь себе и другим. Дебаг в слепую - дело хорошее, хоть и не благодарное, но, для этого надо как минимум обладать огромными знаниями, коих у вас нет. (если бы были, вы бы не задавали такого вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте проверять `response.body()` на `null`

```
String serverAnswer = "";
    if (!response.body() == null){
       String serverAnswer = response.body().string();
    }
return serverAnswer;
```